# How to get product ID of every item of shop list products WC WP

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product

On the WooCommerce store page where the full list of products appears, I want to get the ID of each product to be able to add a form button and directly catch the ID of each product.
I tried to insert into the functions.php:

```
global $product;
$id = $product->get_id();
```

and

```
$product = wc_get_product();
$id = $product->get_id();
```

But, either it doesn't load the page or it returns the page ID of the store, not the product where I click.

I put the form in a popup, and in each product I have a custom field where I put a button

I created a popup where I insert a cf7 shortcode, I use dynamic custom field to pass the ID to it, on my functions.php:

```
add_shortcode( 'product_id', 'get_product_id' );
function get_product_id() {
    //$product_id = sanitize_text_field( $_POST[ 'product_id' ] );
    $id = get_the_ID($product_id);
    return $id;
}
```

the button for the popup I inserted it in the loop in content-product.php

```
echo the_field('compartir');
```

With this I have a button in each product that when clicking opens a popup with the cf7 form. But the id I get is the id of the page, not of each product.

I just used this code, and it returns the same page id, not the product

```
add_action( 'wpcf7_init', 'mp_cf7_custom_shortcode' );
function mp_cf7_custom_shortcode() {    
    wpcf7_add_form_tag('id_producto','get_id_producto');
}
function get_id_producto(){
    $id = get_the_ID($product_id);
    return '<input type="text" name="prod-id" value="'. $id .'" />';
}
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: how do you add the form button? what code do you use for this? your question contains too few details to give a real answer

Comment: I put the form in a popup, and in each product I have a custom field where I put a button.

Comment: now you still have not added the code with which you obtained this, while it is essential for the answer to your question

Comment: Sorry I edited my question adding all the steps and codes I use. I hope it works

Comment: add_shortcode isn't for cf7 shortcodes. Are you trying to add a CF7 Shortcode (form tag) as they're called on CF7 ?

Comment: I just used this code, and it returns the same page id, not the product `add_action( 'wpcf7_init', 'mp_cf7_custom_shortcode' );
function mp_cf7_custom_shortcode() { 
 wpcf7_add_form_tag('id_producto','get_id_producto');
}
function get_id_producto(){
 $id = get_the_ID($product_id);
 return '<input type="text" name="prod-id" value="'. $id .'" />';
}`